# CSS child div overriding parent padding

Tags: html, css

So basically I've wanted to center a child div within the parent div with some padding, and when the child overflows, I still want the padding to be there.

So far using `overflow: hidden` I can hide the content beyond the parent div, but I want it so that it only overflows to the beginning of the padding of the element.

Here's a working sample of my problem:

```css
.post-grid {
    background-color: #1D7B99;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.postview-center {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.postview-center a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-grid">
            <div clas="postview-center">
                <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"> Thisis a very long title that will overflow and I don't want the overflowed text to affect the padding </a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62002128/8620333?

Comment: Ah - thanks! This one helped. Sorry lol I was searching for my question and didn't find something like this

Comment: it's still a recent one so not easy to find ;)